# The css or js file is not working. index.php was not found on this server

Tags: opencart

[This](http://co2consulting.net/e_shodai/upload/) is my site but I am facing a problem. The css or js file is not working. I can't understand.
I using version opencart-2.0.3.1

here is the error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
> /home/co2consulting/public_html/e_shodai/upload/index.php was not
> found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
> mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at
> co2consulting.net Port 80

Comment: Your php file is missing.

Comment: You are putting the wrong URL. `http://co2consulting.net/home/co2consulting/public_html/e_shodai/upload/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js `is what is set in your HTML file, while `http://co2consulting.net/e_shodai/upload/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js` is supposed to appear. Apply the same change on all other files that have this error

Answer (score 0):

Well..by looking at your webpage.

The issue might be coming from 2 places

**First one**

Your `config.php` file is not set up properly

**Second one**

You are missing all of your link/paths inside your `header.tpl` file